# regex for string checking for not null

Tags: java, regex

I need a Java regular expression, which checks that the given String is not Empty and not null . However the expression should ingnore if the user has accidentally given whitespace in the beginning of the input, but allow whitespaces later on.

Comment: "ignore" whitespace at the beginning: does that mean "   " and "  test" fail or pass validation?

Comment: You cannot check for a null reference with a regular expression in Java.  You must separately check that the reference is not null then compare the string with a regular expression.

Comment: @maerics thank you but the thing is that my boss told me to dat using regex only  how can i explain him

Comment: Your boss is _never_ always right.

Comment: your boss told you to do this?  I recommend going to careers.stackoverflow.com and submitting a resume.

Comment: To perform a regalur expression check you need to have a String to check. `null` is not a String object.

Comment: @user1324126: you must tell him the simple fact that he is asking you to do something that is technically not possible.  Period.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 8):

You could do it without using regex.

```
boolean check(String s) {
  return s != null && s.trim().length() > 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1324126 that is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Woot4Moo its not a good idea but still necessary for certain things

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) to check for `nullity` and emptiness:

```
Strings.isNullOrEmpty(myString);
```

And you cannot use regular expressions on a `null` `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
yourString != null && yourString.trim().length() > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check for a null reference with a regular expression in Java. You must separately check that the reference is not null then compare the string with a regular expression.

```
public static boolean isNullEmptyOrWhitespace(String s) {
  return (s==null) || s.matches("^\\s*$");
}
```